# Get latest webkit version with WebView in android

Tags: android, webkit, android-webview, cordova

As you can see on [this page](http://jimbergman.net/webkit-version-in-android-version/) the webkit version with **Android 4.1.1 is 534.30**. Is there some way to embed the latest webkit version in my application like for eg **537.4 which comes with chrome 22** which i have created using [cordova](http://incubator.apache.org/cordova/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We looked at doing this for Cordova Android but it would mean each app would need to include the 40 mb of compiled webkit. This seemed like a non-starter to us. We are eagerly awaiting and SDK that gives us access to a ChromeWebView which would be more up to date compared to a the standard WebView.

Comment: Ok, so will need to wait for ChromeWebView.

Comment: @Ankur That is only a wish. I have no idea whether or not Google will ever provide such an SDK. I've talked to the Googlers on the PhoneGap project and some other Google Developer Advocates but no news so far.

Comment: Are there any Progress on this topic?

Comment: @confile As of Android 4.4, Google now provides incremental updates and the stock browser now uses chrome.