# Android WebView does not show Google-plus Slide Menu

Tags: android, android-webview, overlay, google-plus, html

When traveling to your mobile Google-Plus site(Which I cannot add a link to) and while using chrome, you can tap on the top left icon, or use a right fling gesture to open the left menu panel.

While trying this on my webview, the screen gets darker, as the menu opened, but it is not show, only after tapping on the webview, the menu is shown for a second, and closes, returning to the initial state.

The behavior is the same both on my S4 and Nexus 7.

Code to setup the webview:

```
WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
settings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
settings.setUserAgentString(AndroidUserAgent);
settings.setSavePassword(false);
settings.setSaveFormData(false);
settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {... calling all supers ...});
```

Below are images of the stages.

Any Idea how to show the menu?

Here are the three stages, as best as I could capture them:

**1. Initial state:**

[image]

**2. Menu opened but not shown:**

[image]

**3. Menu shown but on its way to close, after taping on the webview:**

[image]

Comment: What version of Android?

Comment: Android versions 4.2 and 4.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the screenshots provided, it looks like some of the CSS3 transitions in use on the Google+ page were not implemented on the WebKit 534.30. The [WebView does not have the same features and functionality which exist in the latest version of Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7373585/android-webview-vs-phone-browser). This is because WebView [uses WebKit version 534.30](http://jimbergman.net/webkit-version-in-android-version/) which has reduced functionality, and [upgrading the WebKit version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13175915/get-latest-webkit-version-with-webview-in-android) to something more up to date, like version 537.36 (which is used in the latest version of Chrome) isn't feasable at the moment.

Comment: Chrome for Android uses WebKit 537.36 - that's the disconnect; the WebView WebKit version != the build-in browser WebKit version.

Comment: can I hack this with some my own Javascript and css?

Comment: because I don't see any event in the page. the component is not even switch from visible to invisible...